# How can I make Android 6 quick settings show up in the same layout when the screen is locked?

Tags: lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow, quick-settings

Why does lock screen hide some of the elements from the quick settings? This makes intuitive usage of the device nearly impossible because I have to remember to look where the icons are and which ones they are. Like I could have a flashlight on the bottom left and on the lock screen its in the middle. Is there a way to fix this? Because "minor" inconveniences like this make me want to get off android. Too many little annoyances that users have to deal with day-to-day.

Comment: "Some" of the elements? Could you clarify which elements do exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: You can use GravityBox [MM] to have your favorite tile display at lock screen as well. Requires root access and Xposed framework installed.

Answer (score 1):

The elements that have been hidden from your lock screen are hidden for a purpose. Sensitive toggles are not displayed in order to increase the lock screen security.

Due to this, your phone, in unlocked condition shows more toggles than in locked condition. This changes the position of certain toggles and hence your flashlight toggle is moved.

It can be a little inconvenient but you need to live with it since it is making your device safer. Safety by design.